# How to Configure Google OCR in Mendix?

Tags: mendix

Can any one please tell me that **How to configure Google OCR Module in Mendix application?**

I have gone through the documentation but still I didn’t get clear with that.

Can you please tell me that how to configure it? And also I have **created my own Google API key** and I placed in the required field.

Also there is a **one more option(Required Field) **API URL**** I don't know what to do with that **API URL**.

So, Please help me the
**1)Configuration
2)Where to place Google API key
3)What to do with Google URL**

Answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to go through this video, it will walk you through the needed steps to set up Google OCR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43_a7HE0j3I

for more access to the Mendix community you can use:

Mendix Forum: https://forum.mendix.com
Mendix Community Slack: https://mendixcommunity.slack.com/

and you can sign up using : https://signup.mendix.com/link/signup/?medium=social-owned&campaign=GL-MVP-2021-09-01-NourAbuasal

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.